# Блок Try Catch не компилируєтся

Tags: java

```
public void method() {
    System.out.println("1");
    try {
        System.out.println("2");
        throw new Exception("Hello");
        System.out.println("3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("4");
        throw e;
        System.out.println("5");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("6");`од`
    }
    System.out.println("7");
}
```

Почему не компилируется данный код?

Comment: Почему не компилируется? Какая ошибка?

Comment: В чем вы код пишете? Любая маломальская IDE ведь подсветит прямо в коде что не так. 1. У метода не объявлено, что он выбрасывает исключение. 2. В блоках `try` и `catch`, а также после блока `finally` есть недостижимый код. 3. В блоке `finally` вообще какие непонятые символы "од".

Comment: Да 1 я понимаю. А вот почему есть недостежимий код нет